# Unable to change kendos tabstrip text color

Tags: angular, web, kendo-ui, frontend

I have been working on angular with kendos library for some time now. I have recently made a modal which contains tabs. Contents in the tabs are served as required but the thing is I am unable to change the text color of the tab heading. The text have default red color.
I have tried many things like tried to give styles, added [ngClass] directive.But nothing worked for me. I have looked onto the docs but couldn't get anything.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation).

Basically, view encapsulation, which is set to `emulated` by default, means that the styling of each component is encapsulated into the component's view and does not affect other components. This also means that styling that is defined in a parent component doesn't affect the child component.

The styling you are defining in your component which contains the Kendo TabStrip component doesn't penetrate the TabStrip's view encapsulation.

To force the styling to penetrate the view encapsulation, use `:host ::ng-deep` in your CSS selector, like this:

```
:host ::ng-deep .k-tabstrip-items .k-item .k-link {
    color: blue;
}
```

Note: the `::ng-deep` pseudo-class is deprecated and shouldn't be used officially, however there is still no substitute and so we are left with using it until a replacement comes along.

Note 2: The `:host` selector is used to limit the effect of `::ng-deep` to the current component and its children and prevent it from affecting other components.